# Tags like libertarianism

Tags: discussion, tags

So we have here certain very confusing tags, like [rationalism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationalism) or even worse [libertarianism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libertarianism).

Tags become confusing if they lack a description (usage guidance). So what should the well-meaning person do who wants to give those tags a description?

In the case of rationalism, it *seems* that the more educated users understand rationalism à la Descartes and not à la Yudkowsky or something like an standpoint that values reason and is opposed to superstition, etc. Does this justify a corresponding tag description?

In the case of [libertarianism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libertarianism): users apply this to the political philosophy and to the free-will position. What should it be? That's nearly 50:50!

Comment: Some of these terms are legitimately "slippery"..

Comment: Oh geez, as someone who's studied the free-will debate pretty seriously but has not done any political philosophy, this has the potential to get *extremely* confusing. Would it be feasible to split the more 50:50 tags into, like, "libertarian-free-will" and "libertarian-politics"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose that we have [libertarianism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libertarianism) for libertarianism in political philosophy and [libertarianism-free-will](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libertarianism-free-will) for the other one, since the former is clearly more common (in philosophy, not on this site). Same for [rationalism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationalism), and for any other tags which might be like this.

And their descriptions should be updated to avoid confusion.

Comment: this seems sensible. So... are we all okay with this?

Comment: The only caveat I see is that the 'libertarianism' tag is still ambiguous and may be abused by users who don't know better; it *could* be better to rename it to e.g. 'political-libertarianism'. On the other hand, it is not a frequently used tag, so this may be just fine.